# How to use NSURLConnection inside a dispatch_queue or NSThread or NSOperationQueue?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have tried using NSURLConnection inside NSThread and dispatch_queue. The implemented NSURLConnectionDelegate methods are not called. But when I used NSOperation inside of NSThread and NSOperationQueue, the methods are called.

Comment: Does your thread execute a runloop?

Comment: no. i just created a thread and call [thread start] to execute. The url connection is scheduled in currentRunLoop with NSRunLoopCommonModes. Will i need to create a run loop for the thread i have created?(i am just a beginner in Objective-C and iOS programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods aren't being called because your thread or dispatch block completes execution before the delegate methods can be called.  If you want to use `NSURLConnection` in its own thread in this way, as others have suggested you must keep the run loop going.

[Here](http://www.sortedbits.com/nsurlconnection-in-its-own-thread/) is an example.  Basically

```
while(!finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    finished = TRUE;
}
```

All of the above said, would it not be better to use the `NSURLConnection` synchronous API inside of your asynchronous block?  For example, you could wrap your synchronous request inside an `NSOperation`

Comment: I am looking for a solution like this only. Thanks a lot. It works now. I don't want to use NSURLConnection synchronous APIs since I need details of the downloading data (like file name, size, etc.,) which i could get in Asynchronous APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the block-based approach:

```
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){
            // we should check that data is OK
            NSLog(@"Data received");
        }
    }
```